# Error with heroku node js redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, redis

I am trying to deploy an app on heroku and I am running into some errors.
Here is my application log. How would I fix this??

```
2017-11-30T21:25:51.461297+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-30T21:25:51.453647+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the redisExample@1.0.0 start script.
2017-11-30T21:25:51.453488+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!   
2017-11-30T21:25:51.453823+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-11-30T21:25:51.453192+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-11-30T21:25:51.461495+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-11-30T21:25:51.461625+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-11-30T21_25_51_455Z-debug.log
2017-11-30T21:25:51.575216+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-11-30T21:25:51.589604+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-11-30T21:25:52.424042+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calm-bastion-97639.herokuapp.com request_id=e2e56b20-6479-4e14-8199-f2aba1a72ab5 fwd="74.214.48.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-11-30T21:25:52.503819+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calm-bastion-97639.herokuapp.com request_id=4adab6fa-0e19-446b-bc0d-7a7bc0f4e5c5 fwd="74.214.48.190" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

the content of my package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "redisExample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "*",
    "ejs": "^2.4.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "morgan": "*",
    "redis": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ashpixar/redisExample.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ashpixar/redisExample/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ashpixar/redisExample#readme"
}
```

And my js file is
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()

```
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log('all is ok'));

const redis = require('redis')
var client = redis.createClient(process.env.REDIS_URL);
```

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0):

When a procfile is not specified heroku loads a nodejs app by executing npm start.

Your package.json doesn't have a "start" script.

Try adding a start scripts in your package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

[Heroku Procfile documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

I tested the project on my env and I deployed it on heroku, the start script works fine.
You must have missed some steps during the deployment, it is hard to say without logs.

Anyway following these steps you should be able to deploy the app.

1. if you haven't done it yet, you must install the redis addon on
   your heroku instance.

   Download and install the heroku CLI 
   [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli), 
   from the command line run 
   **heroku addons:create heroku-redis:hobby-dev -a**

   This will create the REDIS addon with hobby-dev plan (it's free).
   As soon as you run this command, it will print an instruction in the 
   console to view the progress of the redis addon creation.

   It is something like *Use heroku addons:info redis-curly-19008 to check 
   creation progress*'

   As soon as the addon has been created, you should see in your app 
   settings on Heroku, that it has also added a new env variable 
   REDIS_URL.
2. the *node_modules* folder should not be in your repo, the npm
   modules are installed automatically by heroku when installing the
   application, to install it locally just run the command 
   *npm install* from your root project.

   In order to avoid committing stuff you don't want to, create a file 
   called **.gitignore** in your project root and add the following 
   content:

   ```
   /node_modules
   npm-debug.log
   .DS_Store
   /*.env
   /*.env.*
   /.project
   /.settings
   ```
3. Since you are using github as repository , commit the project changes 
   and deploy
4. Watch the logs and when the deployment is finished, access the url of 
   your app.
   It should be something like:
   **https://yourappname.herokuapp.com/**

I suggest to follow **[this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis)** for more details

Comment: Thanks but that did not work here is my project on github https://github.com/ashpixar/redisExample

Comment: I detailed in the comment